# MySQL Query (joint query and distinct)

Tags: mysql

I have got a question regarding a MySQL query. The relations are given as follows.

```
MOIVEW(title, production_year, country, run_time, major_genre) 
PK: {title, production_year}

PERSON(id, first_name, last_name, year_born) PK:{id}

DIRECTOR(id, title, production_year) 
PK:{title, production_year} 
FK[title] references MOIVE[title, production_year]
FK[id] references PERSON[id]

WRITER(id, title, production_year, credits)
PK:{id, title, production_year}
FK:[title, production_year] references MOVIE[title, production_year]
FK:[id] references PERSON[id]
```

I wonder how to write the following query.

"A person has worked on a movie if this person is a director, a writer, or both a director and writer of this movie. Who has/have worked on the largest number of distinct movies in this database? List the id(s) of
the person(s)."

I am thinking about using join operations and select distinct, but not sure which tables and how they should be joint. Thanks!

Cheers,
Jamie

Comment: create an sql fiddle with some data so we can help http://sqlfiddle.com/